# Ethernet connection very slow in Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, ethernet, ubuntu-drivers

I have problems with my Dell Latitude 5420. My internet connection works fine in Windows 10, but when I use Ubuntu, my connection works fine with Wi-Fi, but not with Ethernet.

- I have 2 or 5 Mb/s download speed with Ethernet and 100 Mb/s with Wi-Fi.
- I have 200 Mb/s upload speed with Ethernet and 100 Mb/s with Wi-Fi.

Here my network hardware (I have an Intel i5 10th generation x64 bits as a processor):

```
*-network:0               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 14.3
   bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
   logical name: wlp0s20f3
   version: 20
   serial: 94:e2:3c:2e:4d:20
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.11.0-36-generic firmware=59.601f3a66.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-59.u ip=192.168.86.35 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:6055294000-6055297fff

*-network:1
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection (13) I219-V
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   logical name: enp0s31f6
   version: 20
   serial: 38:14:28:54:e1:03
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.11.0-36-generic firmware=0.8-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:164 memory:a6100000-a611ffff
```

As you can see, with Ethernet uploading works fine, but not downloading.

Can you help me solve this issue on my Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS laptop?

FYI: It seems that this problem also happens in OpenSUSE Leap 15.3.

Comment: Please edit the question and identify the hardware: `sudo lshw -class network` please post the results in code tags.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Done!

Comment: The only thing that got my attention is the driver, which is e1000e. My guess is that the system is using this generic driver because it can't find anything else. And that your NIC is not really compatible somehow.... hence 32 bit instead of 64 bit? Just a guess... I hope this will help someone to fix your problem, because I'm not the best  when it comes to drivers, I know my limits ^^

Comment: Thanks! @s1mmel ! Yes, it's very strange. I've seen this of 32 bits instead of 64 bits and I don't know because this happens. It seems that is the NIC. I've seen the DELL page to download drivers for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and only appears the DRIVER to update the BIOS. I hope somebody can help me. Many thanks!